# Different image for every block on background grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey I'm trying to figure out a way to have a different image for every block of a grid I created: [image: background-size image grid]

And here's my CSS:

```
background-image: url("my_image.jpg");
background-size: 50px auto;
float: right;
height: 150px;
width: 34%;
```

The only way I could think of was make a bunch of image tags with a fixed position, I'm trying to figure out a much more efficient and cleaner way. I've got all the image urls in a dictionary in jQuery.

```
var faceDict = ["a whole bunch of urls"]
for (var faceIndex = 0; faceIndex < faceDict.length; faceIndex++) {
    $('.face-container').append("<img height='50' src='" + faceDict[faceIndex] + "'/>"); });
```

And all of the code I've got so far in jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUMDF/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sprite with all your image.
Name your css class something like "image_001"...
And with a for loop, you add css class to your block

Comment: Or use `nth-child()` or `nth-of-type()` pseudo classes to set up background positions if browser support is not an issue.

Comment: How will a sprite class work when they're all separate images?

Comment: The point is to compute all your images into a single one (it's called a sprite). Then you define the position of each images (tools can do it for you) in css classes and apply those classes to your block

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use multiple background images seperated by commas..
so perhaps this will work:

```
var faceDict = ["a whole bunch of urls"]
$('.face-container').css({backgroundImage: faceDict.join()});
```

btw seems to have pretty good browser support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=background